# Strange behaviour of \@ command

Tags: pdftex

Consider the following MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpunctuate}
\DeclareRobustCommand\eg{e.g\xperiod}

%% Standard Conditions symbol
\providecommand\barcirc{\mathpalette\@barred\circ}%
\def\@barred#1#2{\ooalign{\hfil$#1-$\hfil\cr\hfil$#1#2$\hfil\cr}}%
\newcommand\stst{^{\protect\barcirc}}%

\begin{document}

Maybe a list, \eg, a, b, c, and d.

\end{document}
```

Which fails to compile with the error message

> ! Use of \@ doesn't match its definition.
>   \xprd@Out ->\xprd@Obj .\@\xspace

Why does this happen? It seems that the code which should only create a symbol redefined the `\@` command but how?

Comment: You need `\makeatletter` if you want to use `@` in this way.

Comment: @IanThompson Indeed... This was actually the condensed MWE from my much larger document where in a file three `\input` statements deep the `\stst` command was defined. Is there some way to tell `(pdf)latex` to warn me if I'm using `\@` commands outside of a `\makeat{letter,other}` group? My header file has grown a bit... so I fear there could be more of this hidden somewhere.

Comment: @elemakil --- None that I am aware of. This doesn't usually cause a problem because commands with `@` generally only appear in packages and classes (where `@` is allowed by default) and (occasionally) in the preamble (where it isn't, so you have to be careful).

Comment: @egreg Yes! I'm not sure how to continue, should I delete the question, mark as duplicate or accept an answer?

Comment: @elemakil No, there's no way to do what you hope. The question I linked is our “canonical” one for this kind of problems. It's up to you choosing whether to delete or keep the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that you must enclose between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` definitions that contain `@`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpunctuate}
\DeclareRobustCommand\eg{e.g\xperiod}

%% Standard Conditions symbol
\makeatletter
\providecommand\barcirc{\mathpalette\@barred\circ}%
\def\@barred#1#2{\ooalign{\hfil$#1-$\hfil\cr\hfil$#1#2$\hfil\cr}}%
\newcommand\stst{^{\protect\barcirc}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Maybe a list, \eg, a, b, c, and d.

\end{document}
```

For more information you must read [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)